# Prove this function defined for a convex, bounded, open, symmetric set $V$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

> $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be open, symmetric and contains 0 . Define $||\cdot||:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
>
> \begin{equation}
> ||x||=\inf\{ \lambda > 0: \lambda^{-1}x\in V \} 
> \end{equation}
>   for all x $\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Prove this is a norm $\iff$ $V$ is convex and bounded with respect to the euclidean metric.

Approach:

1. $||x||\ge 0$ (Done)
2. $||\alpha x||= |\alpha|||x||$ (not done)
3. triangle in equality (not done)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional#Convexity_of_K

Comment: I am not sure how the symmetric property of $V$ is necessary.

Comment: Also assuming that it is a norm how to show that V is convex and bounded?

Comment: Thanks Luiz Cordeiro. This direction of the problem is solved.

Comment: Now you have to show both ways? :O

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Norm induced by convex, open, symmetric, bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495726/norm-induced-by-convex-open-symmetric-bounded-set-in-bbb-rn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends what you mean by symmetric? Inversion symmetric (i.e. contains $x$ iff it contains $-x$)? This is not a norm depending on what you mean. Consider the open set $(-10,10)\times (-1,1)$. This is inversion symmetric, contains the origin, etc. Let $z_1=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$, and $z_2=(1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})$. We have:

\begin{align}
\|z_1\| &= \|z_2\| = 2\\
\|z_1+z_2\| &= 10/\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

Property 2 appears to hold though: That is, this functional is homogeneous.