# Are the $||x||_p$ norms dense in the set of all norms of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Any bounded open symmetric convex $A$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ induces a norm (see [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495726/norm-induced-by-convex-open-symmetric-bounded-set-in-bbb-rn)). This gives some geometrical intuition about how many different norms there are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example my open ball in the specific norm could be a pentagon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or an isocaeder in $\mathbb{R}^3$. From my lectures in university I'm only used to the "classical" (or better canonical) norms of $||x||_p$ with $p\in[1,\infty]$. This makes me wonder if these are somewhat special. What is their measure, are they sparse, are they dense? I'll formulate the last one more precisely for you to answer.

> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ set containing $0$. Let $N$ be the set of all norms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are symmetric in each orthant and $P=\{||.||_p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \;|\; p\in[1,\infty]\}$. Furthermore $N|_A=\{f|_A : f\in N\}$ and $P|_A=\{f|_A : f\in P\}$. Let $(\ell^\infty(A), |||.|||_\infty)$ be the normed vector space of the bounded functions on $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the supremum's norm. Show that $P|_A$ is dense in $N|_A$, both taken as subsets of $\ell^\infty(A)$, or find a counter example.

I merely touched functional analysis of $C^r([a,b])$ and $L^r([a,b])$, so this is a bit much for me, but it seems interesting. Feel free to show other properties of $P|_A$ as well or to reference related papers.

Comment: I think you want to restrict yourself *at least* to absolute norms. Because as suggested by the answer, the $p$-norms are absolute (or monotonic if you prefer) which is a quite particular property for a norm and so you will have trouble to approximate norms which are not "symmetric on each orthant".

Comment: @Surb Not sure what "absolute" means, but I see how "symmetric on each orthant" is important. I restricted $N$ to such ones.

Comment: Have a look at that http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959190085B
Absolute means $\| \ |x| \ \|=\|x\|$ for any $x$ (a mathematical way to say: "symmetric on each orthant")

Comment: I've been thinking a bit further to this problem. Even with the assumption that the norms has to be absolute it is still far to be true. Indeed, if we consider any weighted $p$-norms, then they can not be approximated with non-weighted ones. So you'd probably want to restrict yourself to norms so that $\|e_i\|=1$ for every $i$, where $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the canonical basis. It has a name but I don't remember it. Anyway, it is still not true. There is a large class of non-differentiable norms which can't be approximated. Consider an hexagonal, resp. octagonal, unit ball in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: So probably, you'd need also to add the assumption that the norms are Frechet differentiable. But still in this setting, I don't believe that the $p$-norms are dense. Indeed the $p$-norms in $\Bbb R^2$ are symmetric wrt the axis $(t,t),t \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Finally, you could put a matrix norm on vectors. And these are even more crazy (e.g. a matrix $p,q$-norm).

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the set obtained from $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ by cutting the edges by lines $y=1-x$, $y=-1-x$. Can it be approximated by $l_2^p$ balls?

Comment: Actually, your example is nicely pathologic and could be even worse by doing the same construction but on $[-2,2]\times [-1,1]$ instead.