# Doubt about Minkowski's Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

**Definition**: Let $C$ be an open set in a real normed space $X$ with $0\in C.$ The Minkowski functional of $C$ is defined by 
$$p_{C}(x) = \inf\{\alpha>0:\alpha^{-1}x\in C\},x\in X.$$
Now I am trying to show the following

**Lemma**: Let $C$ and $X$ be as defined earlier and in addition suppose that $C$ is convex, then $p_C$ is a sublinear fuctional on X with 
$$C=\{x:p_C(x)<1\}.$$
In the proof the author starts of by saying, for $x,y\in X$ choose arbritary $\alpha>p_C(x)$ and $\beta>p_C(y).$ Then $\alpha^{-1}x\in C$ and $\beta^{-1}y\in C.$ I don't understand how this can be deduced from the definition of $p_C.$ Perhaps someone can explain?

Comment: I gave an answer showing that $\alpha >p_C(x)$ implies $(\alpha)^{-1}x\in C$. All you need for this is definition of infimum of  a set, convexity of $C$ and the fact that $0\in C$. Can someone say why I was voted down without an explanation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Norm induced by convex, open, symmetric, bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495726/norm-induced-by-convex-open-symmetric-bounded-set-in-bbb-rn)